# Where can I find detailed documentation for IIS server event id's with their description?

Tags: documentation, resources, iis-7

I have been googling for hours now and cant find a thing.

I'm looking for more information on IIS Server event IDs.

There are plenty of articles/blogposts/forum_articles (from MSDN) on some specific events and their resolution etc., but I simply can't find a single document where they have **listed** all the event ids and given a short description of what they are for.

Comment: I normally Google for specific event IDs, rather than trying to find that elusive list of all of them. You'll have far better success doing likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=IIS%20event%20ID&beta=0&ac=3)